# How to remove 'product_code' field in sale order report qweb in Odoo-9?

Tags: odoo-9, qweb

In Odoo system, If you set the product_code (interal reference) in product template, the note also be showed on the qweb report. I would like to get only the product's name in sale order qweb report, Is it possible to remove(or hide) the product_code field report? If it is, please help me to specific the right steps to solve it. Thank you
my qweb code :

```
                    </tr>
                    <t t-set="index" t-value="0"/>
                    <t t-set="product" t-value="0"/>
                    <t t-foreach="doc.handle_orderline(doc.order_line)" t-as="product_line">
                        <t t-set="product_num" t-value="0"/>
                        <t t-set="index" t-value="index + 1"/>
                        <t t-foreach="product_line" t-as="l">
                            <t t-set="product_num" t-value="product_num+1"/>
                            <t t-if="not l.product_uom_qty">
                                <t t-set="index" t-value="index - 1"/>
                            </t>
                            <tr t-if="l.product_uom_qty">
                                <t t-if="product_num == 1">
                                    <td class="text-center" t-att-rowspan="len(product_line)">
                                        <span t-esc="index"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-center" t-att-rowspan="len(product_line)">
                                        <strong><span t-field="l.name"/></strong>
                                        <br/>
                                        <t t-if="l.width_id">( <span style="font-style:italic" t-field="l.width_id.name"/> )</t>
                                    </td>
                                </t>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you update your question with your attempt code ?

Comment: thank for replying me, the flowing code show the name of product in my sale_order_report_documents:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *sale.order.line* object *name* field store value in combination of product name and code. *name* field value set on *onchange* of *Product* field.

So in QWEB report, we need to get value from *product_id* field to display product name.

Replace following code:

```
<strong><span t-field="l.name"/></strong>
```

with

```
<strong><span t-field="l.product_id.name"/></strong>
```

Comment: thank for replying to me, the l.name already been removed however the report was not come out proberly

Comment: Thank again. It works like charm after i login again. Have a nice day bro.

Comment: could you please help me to answer 1 more question, there are two more custom fields in my report, is it possible to group all the product with the same value of integer filed in the qweb like:                                                                                                     (1.55+2.50)x3    (3 ---> is the value of integer filed and 1.55 and 2.50 ís a value of other float field)    if it is possible, I will create an other question topic.

Comment: Please open a new question with details and your attempt code and output. So we can understand your issue.